# Shortest Paths with Cost Property

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I want to look up the top 5 (shortest) path in my graph (Neo4j 3.0.4) from point A to point Z.
The graph consists several nodes that are connected by the relation "CONNECTED_BY". This connection has a cost property that should be minimized.

I started with this:

```
MATCH p=(from:Stop{stopId:'A'}), (to:Stop{stopUri:'Z'}), 
path = allShortestPaths((from)-[:CONNECTED_TO*]->(to))
WITH REDUCE (total = 0, r in relationships(p) | total + r.cost) as tt, path
RETURN path, tt
```

This query returns always the subgraph with the least hops, the cost property is not considered. There exists another subgraph with more hops that has a lower total cost. What I am doing wrong?

Furthermore, I acutally want to get the TOP 5 subgraphs. If I execute this query:

```
MATCH p=(from:Stop{stopUri:'A'})-[r:CONNECTED_TO*10]->(to:Stop{stopUri:'Z'}) RETURN p
```

I can see several paths, but the first one just returns one path.
The path should not contain loops etc. of course.

I want to execute this query via REST API, so a REST Call or cyhper query should do it.

EDIT1:
I want to execute this as REST Call, so I tried the dijkstra algorithm. This seems to be a good way, but I have to calculate the weight by adding 3 different cost properties in the relation. How this could be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

`allShortestPaths` will find the shortest path between two points and then match every path that has the *same number* of hops. If you want to minimize based on cost rather than traversal length, try something like this:

```
MATCH p=(from:Stop{stopId:'A'}), (to:Stop{stopUri:'Z'}), 
path = (from)-[:CONNECTED_TO*]->(to)
WITH REDUCE (total = 0, r in relationships(p) | total + r.cost) as cost, path
ORDER BY cost
RETURN path LIMIT 5
```

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, I know this way, but this is a very long runnig query. And I cannot reduce/limit the relations between the nodes because I dont really know how many are needed.
I want to execute this as REST Call, so I tried the dijkstra algorithm. This seems to be a good way, but I have to calculate the weight by adding 3 different cost properties in the relation. Do you have an idea how I can use more than one cost property?

Comment: Ah, and more important. I tried:
MATCH p=(from:Stop{stopId:'A'}), (to:Stop{stopId:'Z'}), 
path = (from)-[:CONNECTED_TO*15]->(to)
RETURN path LIMIT 5

By this way I get loops. Instead of A -> B -> D -> Z for example I get paths with loops like A -> B -> D -> E -> D -> Z. If I could avoid loops this could be maybe a workaround...